# Basic JQuery Slider: Want to move slide number on top of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I am using the Basic JQuery Slider (http://www.basic-slider.com/).

By default the number markers (showing the total number of slides and which slide you are on) are under the image with a small margin. I want them to appear on the bottom of the images themselves.

**What I have tried:**
**CSS:**
I have pushed the images up by applying a negative margin-top, which worked. I have given them a z-index of 9999 (the same z-index that the left and right buttons have). Yet, for some reason, they appear behind the images, instead of on top of them. This is the problem I need to fix.

**JQuery**
I have looked at the JQuery code for the left right controls and the captions (which are both on top of the slide images, but I do not see anything specific that they have (and which is missing from the number markers) that would allow them to be on top of the images...

I have not posted any code, but can do so if requested. I am using the bjqs.js, bjqs.css, and demo.css found in the package downloaded from the Basic JQuery Slider site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
.bjqs-markers { position:relative; top:-35px; }
```

Comment: This approach seems to work best! Everything's working as expected. Thanks Ben

Comment: Sure thing @ChrisMukherjee - Keep in mind that `z-index` only applies to elements that have the appropriate `position` defined. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `z-index` for this line as `-1`

```
li.bjqs-slide{
   z-index: -1;
}
```

And for this as `+1`

```
ol.bjqs-markers{
   margin-top:-35px;
   z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked. I had tried giving the li.bjqs-slide a z-index of 1, and the ol.bjqs-markers a higher z-index of 9999. Do you know why this didn't work? (I don't think I fully understand z-index haha)

Comment: Oh! I just noticed that this approach has a small flaw: The numbers are not clickable. So while they show up above the images, they cannot be used to change the slide. Thanks anyways

Comment: give `ul.bjqs{z-index:-1;}` and the link will be clickable